# Linux glibc, gcc, стандартные потоки. Где создаются стандартные потоки?

Tags: linux

Где код который создаёт стандартные потоки ввода, вывода, ошибки для нового процесса? Или всё процессы просто наследуют стандартные потоки? Тогда где код создающий потоки для первого процесса?

man 3 stdio

```
       При запуске  программы  предопределяются  три  текстовых  потока,  которые  не  следует
       открывать  явно:  стандартный  ввод  (standard  input)  (для  чтения  условного ввода),
       стандартный вывод (standard output) (для записи условного вывода) и  стандартный  поток
       ошибок  (standard error) (для вывода диагностики). Сокращённые названия потоков: stdin,
       stdout и stderr.
```

Никто не дал ответа на вопрос. Когда вы делаете что-то подобное.

```
grep '.' >&- <(echo Y)
```

Оболочка Bash закрывает дескриптор который содержит поле `_fileno` структуры `FILE` для `stdout` - поток стандартного вывода, для нового процесса после `fork`   и перед `execve(grep)`. Утилита `grep` использует функции `stdio` для вывода результата поиска. В итоге функция вывода `stdio` передают системному вызову `write` дескриптор которого нету. Системный вызов возвращает ошибку и утилита выводит причину ошибки на экран. Я хотел чтоб мне объяснили где создаются структуры стандартных потоков, при старте процесса. Или они просто приезжают с процессом он же копируется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Где этот код в бинарнике, кто его туда вставляет? На каком этапе вызывается.

Comment: @quest начальное значение для переменной `stdout` захардкожено в glibc, файл  libio/stdfiles.c. В этом файле переменная `_IO_2_1_stdout_` определяется как литерал типа `_IO_FILE_plus` в котором поле `file._fileno` присвоено значение 1. Это значение попадает в процесс при загрузке библиотеки `libc.so.6` при старте процесса.

Answer (score 5):

Код, создающий потоки для переменных `stdin, stdout, stderr` находится в файле [glibc/libio/stdio.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/stdio.c;h=fd94b76b566b7af94cc752696717216226a945c9;hb=refs/heads/master):

```
FILE *stdin = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stdin_;
FILE *stdin = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stdin_;
FILE *stdout = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stdout_;
```

Переменные `_IO_2_1_...` определены в файле [glibc/libio/stdfiles.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/stdfiles.c;h=00bf239299c31067f54b416ffabab6593280e369;hb=refs/heads/master) как обёртки типа `FILE` вокруг файловых дескрипторов 0,1,2.

Судя по вашему вопросу, вас интересует, откуда берутся файловые дескрипторы с номерами 0, 1 и 2. Ответ - из процесса предка. Процессы в Linux в большинстве своём порождаются парой системных вызовов `fork/clone + execve`. Процессы, порождаемые `fork`, наследуют таблицу открытых файлов предка. Системный вызов `execve` так же не меняет таблицу открытых файлов (за исключением файлов, открытых с флагом `O_CLOEXEC`).

> Где код который создаёт стандартные потоки ввода, вывода, ошибки для нового процесса?

На ваш вопрос нет одного ответа. Всё зависит от того, как именно был порождён процесс. Например, если он был запущен из `bash`, то этот код находится в файле  [execute_cmd.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c)

Если же вы сами порождаете процесс, то этот код находится в вашей программе. Вот маленький пример. Он запускает процесс с именем `child.exe` и перенаправленными потоками: вход `child.exe` читает из файла с именем `input`, стандартный вывод пишет в файл `out`, а ошибки в файл `err`. Файловые дескрипторы в этом примере открываются в порождённом процессе между `fork` и `execv`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t cpid, w;
    int wstatus;

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (cpid == 0)
    { /* Code executed by child */
        int fd0=-1, fd1=-1, fd2=-1;
        FILE *ch_log;
        int ret = 0;

        ch_log = fopen("./child.log", "w");
        if (ch_log == NULL) {
            perror("Failed to open log");
            exit(-1);
        }
        fprintf(ch_log, "Hello\n");
        close(0);
        close(1);
        close(2);

        fd0 = open("./input", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd0 < 0) {
            fprintf(ch_log, "Failed to open input: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            ret = -1;
            goto close_log;
        } else {
            fprintf(ch_log, "Opened input: %d\n", fd0);
        }
        fd1 = open("./out", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
        if (fd1 < 0) {
            fprintf(ch_log, "Failed to open out: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            ret = -1;
            goto close_log;
        } else {
            fprintf(ch_log, "Opened out: %d\n", fd1);
        }

        fd2 = open("./err", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
        if (fd2 < 0) {
            fprintf(ch_log, "Failed to open err: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            ret = -1;
            goto close_log;
        } else {
            fprintf(ch_log, "Opened err: %d\n", fd2);
        }
        close_log:
        fclose(ch_log);
        if (ret < 0) {
            if (fd0 >= 0) { close(fd0); }
            if (fd1 >= 0) { close(fd1); }
            if (fd2 >= 0) { close(fd2); }
            exit(-1);
        }
        execl("./child.exe", (char*)NULL);
        exit(ret);
    }
    else
    { /* Code executed by parent */
        do
        {
            w = waitpid(cpid, &wstatus, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
            if (w == -1)
            {
                perror("waitpid");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (WIFEXITED(wstatus))
            {
                printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));
            }
            else if (WIFSIGNALED(wstatus))
            {
                printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(wstatus));
            }
            else if (WIFSTOPPED(wstatus))
            {
                printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(wstatus));
            }
            else if (WIFCONTINUED(wstatus))
            {
                printf("continued\n");
            }
        } while (!WIFEXITED(wstatus) && !WIFSIGNALED(wstatus));
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

**ВДОГОНКУ**

Как убедиться, что `stdout` инициализируется статически.

Для простоты не будем связываться с динамической линковкой, посмотрим на статически слинкованный файл. Испытания будем проводить на файле `some.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE z = *stdout;

    printf("stdout == &_IO_2_1_stdout_: %d\n", stdout == &_IO_2_1_stdout_);

    printf("_flags: %o\n", z._flags);
    printf("_IO_read_ptr: %p\n", z._IO_read_ptr);
    printf("_IO_read_end: %p\n", z._IO_read_end);
    printf("_IO_read_base: %p\n", z._IO_read_base);
    printf("_IO_write_base: %p\n", z._IO_write_base);
    printf("_IO_write_ptr: %p\n", z._IO_write_ptr);
    printf("_IO_write_end: %p\n", z._IO_write_end);
    printf("_IO_buf_base: %p\n", z._IO_buf_base);
    printf("_IO_buf_end: %p\n", z._IO_buf_end);
    printf("_IO_save_base: %p\n", z._IO_save_base);
    printf("_IO_backup_base: %p\n", z._IO_backup_base);
    printf("_IO_save_end: %p\n", z._IO_save_end);
    printf("_markers: %p\n", z._markers);
    printf("_chain: %p\n", z._chain);
    printf("_fileno: %d\n", z._fileno);
    printf("_flags2: %o\n", z._flags2);  
}
```

Компилируем: `gcc -static some.c`
Получаем: `ll a.out` => `845152 Feb 22 22:03 a.out*`
Запускаем:

```
$ ./a.out 
stdout == &_IO_2_1_stdout_: 1
_flags: 37353220204
_IO_read_ptr: (nil)
_IO_read_end: (nil)
_IO_read_base: (nil)
_IO_write_base: (nil)
_IO_write_ptr: (nil)
_IO_write_end: (nil)
_IO_buf_base: (nil)
_IO_buf_end: (nil)
_IO_save_base: (nil)
_IO_backup_base: (nil)
_IO_save_end: (nil)
_markers: (nil)
_chain: 0x6b9580
_fileno: 1
_flags2: 0
```

Первая строка подтверждает, что `stdout == &_IO_2_1_stdout_`
Последующие строки печатают часть полей объекта типа `FILE`, на который указывает значение символа `stdout`

Следующий шаг: смотрим таблицу символов получившегося файла:

```
$ objdump -x a.out | grep stdout
00000000006b97a0 g     O .data  0000000000000008 stdout
00000000006b9360 g     O .data  00000000000000e0 _IO_2_1_stdout_
00000000006b97a0 g     O .data  0000000000000008 .hidden _IO_stdout
```

Символы `stdout` и `_IO_stdout` занимают 8 байтов по смещению `6b97a0` от начала файла, в секции `.data`
Символ `_IO_2_1_stdout_` находится по смещению `6b9360` тоже в секции `.data`.

Далее: смотрим, как эти символы используются в коде приложения.

```
$ objdump --disassemble a.out | grep -E '(<[^>]+>:|stdout)' | grep stdout -B1
0000000000400b6d <main>:
  400b87:       48 8b 05 12 8c 2b 00    mov    0x2b8c12(%rip),%rax        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
  400caa:       48 8b 15 ef 8a 2b 00    mov    0x2b8aef(%rip),%rdx        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
  400cb1:       48 8d 05 a8 86 2b 00    lea    0x2b86a8(%rip),%rax        # 6b9360 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>
--
000000000040f960 <_IO_printf>:
  40f9d9:       48 8b 3d c0 9d 2a 00    mov    0x2a9dc0(%rip),%rdi        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
--
000000000040ff60 <_IO_new_fclose>:
  40fff4:       48 39 1d a5 97 2a 00    cmp    %rbx,0x2a97a5(%rip)        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
--
00000000004106d0 <_IO_wfile_underflow>:
  41083c:       48 8b 2d 5d 8f 2a 00    mov    0x2a8f5d(%rip),%rbp        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
  41089f:       48 8b 3d fa 8e 2a 00    mov    0x2a8efa(%rip),%rdi        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
  410cbf:       48 8b 3d da 8a 2a 00    mov    0x2a8ada(%rip),%rdi        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
--
0000000000412900 <_IO_new_file_underflow>:
  41294a:       4c 8b 2d 4f 6e 2a 00    mov    0x2a6e4f(%rip),%r13        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
  412ae4:       48 8b 3d b5 6c 2a 00    mov    0x2a6cb5(%rip),%rdi        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
  412b75:       48 8b 3d 24 6c 2a 00    mov    0x2a6c24(%rip),%rdi        # 6b97a0 <_IO_stdout>
```

Символ `stdout` используется в функциях `main`, `_IO_printf`, `_IO_new_fclose`, `_IO_wfile_underflow`, `_IO_new_file_underflow`. Если поглядеть в дизассемблированный код, то можно глазками убедиться, что этот символ используется только для чтения. Так как приложение слинковано статически, то нет никакого другого кода, в котором переменные `stdout` и `_IO_2_1_stdout_` могли бы инициализироваться. То есть это данные, статически инциализированные компилятором.

Финальный шаг: подтверждение того, что `stdout` - это статический указатель на `_IO_2_1_stdout_`

Извлечём объектный файл `stdio.o` из библиотеки `libc.a`: `$ ar x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a stdio.o`
Теперь посмотрим таблицу символов и релокации этого объектного файла:

```
$ objdump -t -r stdio.o

stdio.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .data.rel      0000000000000000 .data.rel
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 g     O .data.rel      0000000000000008 stderr
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _IO_2_1_stderr_
0000000000000000 g     O .data.rel      0000000000000008 .hidden _IO_stderr
0000000000000008 g     O .data.rel      0000000000000008 stdout
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _IO_2_1_stdout_
0000000000000008 g     O .data.rel      0000000000000008 .hidden _IO_stdout
0000000000000010 g     O .data.rel      0000000000000008 stdin
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _IO_2_1_stdin_
0000000000000010 g     O .data.rel      0000000000000008 .hidden _IO_stdin


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.data.rel]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000000 R_X86_64_64       _IO_2_1_stderr_
0000000000000008 R_X86_64_64       _IO_2_1_stdout_
0000000000000010 R_X86_64_64       _IO_2_1_stdin_
```

Символ `stdout` занимает 8 байт по смещению 8 в секции `.data.rel`, а таблица релокации предписывает записать в эту секцию по смещению 8 адрес символа `_IO_2_1_stdout_`.

Итого. Когда линкер собирает исполнимый файл, в котором упоминается `stdout`, он берёт этот символ из объектного файла `libc.a/stdio.o` и в соответствии с таблицей релокации подставляет в значение этого символа смещение символа `_IO_2_1_stdout_` из объектного файла `libc.a/stdfiles.o`, то есть инициализирует `stdout` как указатель на `_IO_2_1_stdout_`

Comment: Меня не интересуют дескрипторы полученные например с помощью системного вызова `open`, которые впоследствии и использует `stdio`. Меня интересует где создаются стандартные потоки  при запуске программы.

Comment: И зачем вы привели этот код? Он ни как не отвечает на мой вопрос. Где код который создает стандартные потоки при старте процесса? Прочтите вопрос ещё раз, я там кусочек документации `stdio` вставил.

Comment: @quest ответ на цитату из man stdio в первых двух абзацах: в glibc переменные stdin, stdout, stderr инициализируются в файле libio/stdio.c

Comment: Мне вот тоже интересно. Вроде дали ответ: Этот код вставляется компилятором и вызывается при старте. Но где доказательства, что это так? Как это пощупать? Или вы просто предполагаете что это так?

Comment: @answer добавил раздел "Вдогонку" с анализом объектных файлов библиотеки `libc` для доказательства того, что `stdout` инциализируется статически

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас обычно shell из которого мы запускаем свои команды сам запускается из эмулятора терминала (например, у меня это `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server`).

Именно он создает псевдотерминал к которому цепляет дескрипторы 0, 1 и 2 (stdin, stdout, stderr) процесса, в котором потом запускает shell (у меня это bash).

Таким образом, код, который вас интересует, находится в эмуляторе терминала.

Если говорить о библиотечных (в libc) вызовах, то запуск процесса под псевдотерминалом может быть сделана в [forkpty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty), а для переключения потоков перед exec-ом используется, например, [dup3](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)

Comment: Есть сущность Glibc стандартные потоки. Документация по stdio говорит что при запуске процесса создаются три потока stdin, stdout, stderr. Где код создающий эти потоки?

Comment: Вас интересует, именно, `FILE *stdin, *stdout, *stderr;`? Если да, то думаю, стартовый код [ctr0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) (часть бублиотеки, выполняется перед main) делает fdopen для них.

Comment: Да интересуют `FILE *stdin, *stdout, *stderr;` Где код создающий эти потоки?

Comment: Мне кажется, он д.б. в crt0. Наверное можно посмотреть через strace

Comment: Через `strace` вы ничего не увидите в данном случае.

Comment: @quest, да, вы правы.  Кстати,  `gcc -v` + `objdump` тоже быстро не получилось. Сдаюсь -)

Answer (score 0):

Потоки stdin/stdout/stderr создают терминалы: программы getty, sshd и эмуляторы терминалов.

Самый простой случай - терминал без иксов.

Потоки создаются в программе agetty вот в этой строчке

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/agetty.c#L1059  смотрите строчки:

Открывается терминал /dev/ttyX как файл

```
if (open(buf, O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0) != 0)
```

Вывод делается из ввода

```
if (dup(STDIN_FILENO) != 1 || dup(STDIN_FILENO) != 2)
```

Далее они копируются в программу login, потом из неё в программу bash, а далее их получает Ваша программа.

Предопределяются - не значит создаются. В этом случае они устанавливаются родительским процессом.

Дескриптор это почти поток. Далее процитирую

> Код, создающий потоки для переменных stdin, stdout, stderr находится в
> файле glibc/libio/stdio.c:
>
> FILE *stdin = (FILE *) &*IO_2_1_stdin*; FILE *stdin = (FILE *)
> &*IO_2_1_stdin*; FILE *stdout = (FILE *) &*IO_2_1_stdout*; Переменные
> *IO_2_1*... определены в файле glibc/libio/stdfiles.c как обёртки типа FILE вокруг файловых дескрипторов 0,1,2.

Comment: Ответ @eri странный. Там дескрипторы получаются. Не вижу создания потоков.

Comment: считайте его уточнением ответа @PakUula (где именно предок их взял)